# Proving matrix $A$ is never similar to $A + I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My question is about similarities, I want to prove it, so I looked up the topic. However, I couldn't understand how to prove that assertion.

Why is $A$ never similar to $A + I$?

Here $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, and $I$ is the identity matrix.

I know for the similarities that property is very important:
$$A= P'B P$$
if $A$ is similar to $B$. But how can I prove it is not similar to $A+I$?

Comment: Similar matrices have the same eigenvalues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether this is true depends on the scalar field! (As well as on the size of the matrix...)

"Similar matrices have the same eigenvalues" is the natural first thought. "What if there are no eigenvalues?" Mumble about algebraic closure... I say to myself even if there are no eigenvalues there *is* something like the sum of the eigenvalues, namely the trace. Similar matrices have the same trace, qed.

Except wait, why can't $I$ have trace zero? And hence the counterexample. If we're talking, say, about $2\times 2$ matrices over $\Bbb Z_2$: Let $$A=\left[\begin{array}{}1&0\\0&0\end{array}\right].$$ Then $A$ *is* similar to $A+I$.

Comment: (The moral of the story is that matrices are similar *over a field*, and this relation may vary when we change such field.)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks. It was actually an overview of my thoughts on the matter. Then it took a few minutes to find the Latex for a matrix (don't know any Latex, been using Tex). Then when I posted it was almost embarassing to see it was also an overview of the thread...

Answer (score 3):

Even easier: assuming that we are in characteristic $0$ (or in a characteristic that does not divide the dimension of our matrices) and that $A$ and $A+I$ are similar matrices, they must have the same trace, but:
$$ \text{Tr}(A+I) = n+\text{Tr}(A), $$
hence $A$ and $A+I$ cannot be similar. However, if we take characteristic $k$ and dimension $k$, there are counter-examples, as shown above by David C. Ullrich.

Comment: Well, what about positive characteristic...? =)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Precisely. See my answer...